# Changing checked item properties in ngRepeat nested list

Tags: list, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-lists

[My code - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sy1eDrdPzHvCHLEXxJrG?p=preview)

I added a `checkbox` to all my `objects` in a `nested list` created by `ngRepeat`.
My `objects`are divided to `folders` and `files`.

I want to do something simple, when I check the box of few files and folders I want 
to change their status by using a `select-option`.

e.g.

[image: e.g.]

I have a serious problem `binding` my `list` `objects` `status` property with `select-option`
The problem is even harder when I try to apply it on couple of `objects` inside when the `list` is nested.

**MY CODE**

var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

```
//controllers

webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope, Votes) {
    $scope.votes  = Votes.getVotesByRatingID(3);


    $scope.expand = function(vote) {
       console.log("show")

       $scope.vote = vote;
       $scope.ip = vote.ip;
       $scope.date = vote.created;

    }


});


//services


webApp.factory('Votes', [function() {

    //temporary repository till integration with DB this will be translated into restful get query
    var votes = [
        {
            id: '1',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.0',
            status: 'Pending',
            show: false,
            folder: [
                {
                    id: '142',
                    created: 1381583344653,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '3',
                    rate: 5,
                    ip: '198.168.0.0',
                    status: 'Approved'
                },
                {
                    id: '1532',
                    created: 1381583344653,
                    updated: '222212',
                    ratingID: '3',
                    rate: 5,
                    ip: '198.168.0.0',
                    status: 'Pending'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ratingID: '2',
            file: {
                id: '111',
                created: 1381583344653,
                updated: '222212',
                ratingID: '4',
                rate: 5,
                ip: '198.168.0.1',
                status: 'Spam'
            }
        },
        {
            ratingID: '3',
            file: {
                id: '2',
                created: 1382387322693,
                updated: '222212',
                ratingID: '3',
                rate: 1,
                ip: '198.168.0.2',
                status: 'Approved'
            }
        },
        {
            ratingID: '3',
            file: {
                id: '22',
                created: 1382387322693,
                updated: '222212',
                ratingID: '3',
                rate: 1,
                ip: '198.168.0.3',
                status: 'Spam'
            }
        },
        {
            ratingID: '3',
            file: {
                id: '222',
                created: 1382387327693,
                updated: '222212',
                ratingID: '3',
                rate: 1,
                ip: '198.168.0.4',
                status: 'Approved'
            }
        }
    ];

    votes.getVotesByRatingID = function(ratingID) {
        var i, list;
        list = [];

        for (i = 0; i < votes.length; i += 1) {
            if (votes[i].ratingID == ratingID ) {
                list.push(votes[i]);
            }//end if
        }//end outer loop

        return list;
    };

    return votes;


}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller='VotesCtrl'>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li class="check">

        </li>
        <li class="created">
            <a>CREATED</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            <b>IP ADDRESS</b>
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            <b>STATUS</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="vote in votes">
        <li class="check" ng-show="!vote.file">
          <input type="checkbox"></input>
        </li>
        <li  class="created">
            <a href="#">{{vote.created|date}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.status}}
        </li>

        <li class="check" ng-show="vote.file">
          <input type="checkbox"></input>
        </li>
        <li class="created" ng-click="expand(vote.file)">
            <a href="#">{{vote.file.created|date}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.file.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.file.status}}
        </li>

        <ul class="file" ng-repeat="file in vote.folder">
          <li class="check">
            <input type="checkbox"></input>
          </li>
          <li class="created" ng-click="expand(file)">
              <a  href="#">{{file.created|date}}</a>
          </li>
          <li class="ip">
              {{file.ip}}
          </li>
          <li class="status">
              {{file.status}}
          </li>
        </ul>

    </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="details">
    <h3>Details:</h3>
      <div>DATE: {{date|date}}</div>
      <div>IP: {{ip|date}}</div>
      <div>STATUS: 
        <select ng-model="vote.status">
          <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
          <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
          <option value="Trash">Trash</option>
          <option value="Spam">Spam</option>
       </select>
       <p>{{vote.status|json}}</p>
      </div>
   <div>
</body>
```

Comment: Create options using `ng-options`.

Comment: I've never understood what is so good in `ng-options`. Anyway I don't see how it solves my problem

Comment: Also need to bind the checkboxes using `ng-model`

Comment: I tried that but I cannot find the proper way to do binding, if you have a solution please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind model to the checkboxes and call a method on select's change:

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes">
    <li class="check" ng-show="!vote.file">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vote.cb"></input>
    </li>
    ...
    <ul class="file" ng-repeat="file in vote.folder">
        <li class="check">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="file.cb"></input>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</ul>
... 
<select ng-change="change()" ng-model="votes.status" 
ng-options="status for status in statuses">
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];

$scope.change = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.votes.length; i++){
        if($scope.votes[i].cb){
            $scope.votes[i].status =$scope.votes.status;
        }
        if($scope.votes[i].folder){
            for(var j = 0; j < $scope.votes[i].folder.length; j++){
                if($scope.votes[i].folder[j].cb){
                    $scope.votes[i].folder[j].status =$scope.votes.status;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make it to work in plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/eiQos8AdOTjP3pcBtODG?p=preview it is not working for me

Comment: Your last plunker had a minor bug I managed to fix:http://plnkr.co/edit/nP3UjGPKdDxfy85NuyUP, now it is working thanks!